# Length menu being discarded due to sDom in Jquery Datatable?

Tags: datatables

I have this:

```
oTable = $("#bla").dataTable({ 
    "iDisplayLength": 50, 
    "aLengthMenu": [[5, 25, 50, 100, 250, -1], [5, 25, 50, 100, 250, "All"]], 
    "sDom": "<'call-header'<'dthead'><'ttools'T><'filterinput'f>r><'dttoolbar'><'dataTables_scroll'<'dataTables_scrollBody't>><'call-footer'<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>>",

.... });
```

If I comment out the sDom part, I get my length menu and I am able to select the number of items to show on the page. But with the SDOM variable, this just disappears.

I've tried combinations of adding:

```
<'dataTables_length'>
```

But I think I am misunderstanding how it works. Can anyone clarify how this must be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation for sDom](http://datatables.net/ref#sDom) - the sDom code for Length changing is `l`.

Here the length menu is being inserted as the very first control :

```js
sDom: "<'call-header'<'dthead'>l<'ttools'T><'filterinput'f>r><'dttoolbar'><'dataTables_scroll'<'dataTables_scrollBody't>><'call-footer'<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>>"
                            ---^---
```

fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/eCrhb/**